# UBUNTU 15.10: after most recent kernel update to 4.2.0-17.21, wi-fi, USB mouse and brightness not working

Tags: kernel, 15.10

After most recent kernel update to 4.2.0-17.21 in Ubuntu 15.10, wi-fi, USB  mouse and brightness are not working. I used Advanced Options in GRUB to start system normally. However, how to fix this permanently?

Comment: boot an old kernel and file bug reports =) I would remove the new kernel and put the kernel package on hold.

Comment: I don't know how to file a bug in Ubuntu... official bug reporting documentation is rather confusing. So, I am running Ubuntu with older kernel... and if I run with new, I don't have Internet... so how to file a bug?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug .

Comment: If you have submitted a bug report could you comment here with a link to it? I'm having the same problem and would like to follow your bug report. Thanks.